# Compare number of a specific process to a number

Tags: batch-file, variable-assignment

I get the number of a specific process with the help of this thread:

[How to count amount of processes with identical name currently running, using a batchfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550200/how-to-count-amount-of-processes-with-identical-name-currently-running-using-a?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

I hope to assign the result of this command to a variable, then compare the variable with a number. My code is listed as below:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set procName=chrome.exe
set a=tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %procName%" 2>NUL | find /I /C "%procName%"
if !a! equ 1 (
    echo !a!
    echo %procName% starts to run...
) else (
    echo !a!
    echo %procName% has not run!
)
```

Here I got '0' for
'set a=tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %procName%" 2>NUL | find /I /C "%procName%"' command.
It also gives me "Echo closed" hint for 'echo !a!'.

FYI, when running the following command in cmd

> tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe" 2>NUL | find
>    /c /i "chrome.exe"
>
> set a=tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe" 2>NUL
>   | find /c /i "chrome.exe"

the output is 16 and 0 respectively.

What's the reason? How could I assign the result of a command to a variable? How to compare the variable to a number?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Well, `set a=tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe" 2>nul | find /c "chrome.exe"` does not work for me either.  Which is good because I don't know how that was supposed to work.

I believe that this will be faster, because it doesn't have the overhead of `FIND.EXE` and writing, reading and deleting `proc_temp`.

```
set a=0
for /f "skip=3" %%x in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe"') do set /a a=a+1
echo Total chrome.exe tasks running: %a%
```

**EDIT:** I just discovered that `set /a` does not require expanded variables and so removed the `setlocal` and `endlocal` commands and altered the `set /a` syntax.

Comment: I found a small error in my code that would cause it to count one too many lines.  I've edited my answer and corrected the problem. I changed `skip=2` to `skip=3`. I also remove some unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0):

after this line in environment a has the pid of the process sought

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%a in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq %procName%"') do if !%%a!==!%procName%!  set a=%b
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution:

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq %procName%" 2>nul | findstr /i %procName% | find /c /v "">proc_temp
set /p current_num= < proc_temp
echo !current_num!
```

Also I think the code can be simplified. Hope some of you can give brief version :)

Comment: BTW, when you call another bat before you use the variable, you SHOULD use 'call' in front of the bat you want to call, or the variable will be disabled. See a successful example:

    tasklist /fi "imagename eq %procName%" 2>nul | findstr /i %procName% | find /c /v "">proc_temp
    call Other.bat
    set /p current_num= < proc_temp
    echo !current_num!

And a failed one:

    tasklist /fi "imagename eq %procName%" 2>nul | findstr /i %procName% | find /c /v "">proc_temp
    Other.bat               rem This would disable current_num
    set /p current_num= < proc_temp
    echo !current_num!

Comment: By using both `findstr.exe` and `find.exe` you are needlessly searching for the same information twice. Also, `find /v` removes the lines that it finds, screwing up the count. To use your code here you should change the first line to read `tasklist /fi "imagename eq %procName%" 2>nul | find /c "%procName%" > proc_temp`.