# How can I count the number of curl instances from a batch file and put it into a variable?

Tags: batch-file, variables

Using information from the answer below, I tried

```
set curlsnum=tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq curl.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /C "curl.exe"
echo %curlsnum%
```

and this returns

```
set curlsnum=tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq curl.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /C "curl.exe"
0

echo
ECHO is on.
```

So it counts it properly, but for some reason the zero doesn't make it into the variable. Set /a doesn't make any difference either. I must be missing something obvious but can't work out what. Do variables have to be natural numbers or something weird?!

[How to count amount of processes with identical name currently running, using a batchfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550200/how-to-count-amount-of-processes-with-identical-name-currently-running-using-a)

Comment: Did you try `echo %curlsnum%` I bet it's not what you expect. [Get output of command to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+%5Bbatch-file%5D+get+output+of+a+command+to+a+variable)

Comment: Hi, yeah it's in the top codeblock. On the bottom we can see it just returns "echo", which tells me whether echo is currently on or off. In other words it doesn't return a zero - it doesn't return anything at all - and that's what I don't understand.

Comment: ok, what's the output of `set curlsnum=tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq curl.exe" 2>NUL`? So, how many `curl.exe` could you expect?

Comment: There can be used `for /F %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq curl.exe" /NH ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /C "curl.exe"') do set "curlsnum=%%I"` to get the number of running `curl.exe` tasks output by `find` assigned to an environment variable with name `curlsnum`. Run in a command prompt window `for /?` and `tasklist /?` and `find /?` and `set /?` for the usage helps of the four [Windows commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set` sets a variable to a string. If that string happens to be a command, the variable will contain the *command*, not its *output*.

To catch the output to a variable in batch, you need a `for /f` loop (see `for /?`):

```
for /f %%a in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq curl.exe" 2^>NUL ^| find /I /C "curl.exe"') do set "curlsnum=%%a"
echo %curlsnum%
```

Comment: `2^>NUL` is not really necessary as long as the arguments are correct which is the case here with `/FI "IMAGENAME eq curl.exe"`. The information message "*INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.*" is output by __TASKLIST__ to __STDOUT__ on no matching task found. I have made in the past quite often the same "mistake" which is not really a mistake and now my template for __TASKLIST__ usage is correct defined in used text editor.

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling it was something like this but I had a lot of lines like *set /a totalpages = %totalrecords%/%pagesize%*, so I didn't quite get that some commands need something different.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with powershell into a batch file like this :

```dos
@echo off
Title count instances of process
Set MyProcess=curl
Call :Count_Process "%Myprocess%" Count
echo There are %Count% of "%Myprocess%"
pause
Exit /B
::-------------------------------------------------------------------
:Count_Process <ProcessName> <Count>
@for /f "delims=" %%# in (
    'PowerShell -C "(Get-Process | Where {$_.Name -ieq '%1'}).count"'
) do Set "%2=%%#
Exit /B
::-------------------------------------------------------------------
```